# Facebook Graph Api v2.0 me/photos returns empty for all users except me who created the app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, user-permissions

I am using this code below, which uses the parse sdk:

```
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
[FBSession.activeSession requestNewReadPermissions:@[@"user_photos"] completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {

if (!error) {FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
             FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:[FBSession activeSession]
             graphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/photos"]];
[connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {}];
[connection start];
```

This all works fine for me it downloads all the most recent photos. But for anyone else, who has logged in via Facebook on the app the result returns:

```
{
data =     (
    )
}
```

Why am i, the developer, the only one who is able to access his photos? Is there a setting in the app settings on Facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [**v2.0**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) onwards, the permissions other than `public_profile`, `email` and the `user_friends` need to the submitted for review before you can make your app **live**; until then, only the testers/admin/developers of the app will be able to test app with those permissions.

See here for details on the [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login).

Answer (score -1):

yes there is, 
You have to go on you facebook developer account -> go on the application -> add a contact email.

After that go to status & review -> and set Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? to yes.
Now it should work

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. I have already added a contact email and set the features available to the public as yes.

Comment: Ahh I think I have to submit the "user_photos" to login permissions.